# Log4Cplus loading configuration file

Tags: c++, log4cplus

I can't figure out how to initialize and load configuration file of log4cplus.
Does anyone give me hints ?
Thanks in advance.
K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`PropertyConfigurator::doConfigure()`](http://log4cplus.sourceforge.net/docs/html/classlog4cplus_1_1PropertyConfigurator.html#ac8a789fdb849ec689ead3cad69bd86e5) to load properties file and configure log4cplus using it.

Comment: log4cplus::PropertyConfigurator::doConfigure("D:/Test/log4cplus_configure.ini");